# Is there an a query to retrive same column values as two columns depend on data value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `comments` where a column name `status` (has 0 for deactive, 1 for an active state) now I need help with select query to seperate two columns counting both 0 & 1 and group by post id column.

I tried two seperate queries but it is not optimal. I am a Windows user using XAMPP 3.2.2.

> SELECT postid, count(id) AS approved FROM comments WHERE status = 0 GROUP BY postid;

the result would show three columns (`postid`,`approved`,`disapproved`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    postid,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 END) AS approved,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 END) AS disapproved
FROM comments
GROUP BY
    postid;
```

The idea here is to take a conditional sum/count for each `postid`, depending on the value of the `status`.  The problem with putting this logic in the `WHERE` clause is that you can't simultaneously check for both statuses there.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are 0 and 1, you can simplify the logic to:

```
SELECT postid,
       SUM(status) as approved,
       SUM(1 - status) as disapproved
FROM comments c
GROUP BY postid;
```